# Can you disable a UIButton without disabling its attached UIGestureRecognizers?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIButton with 2 functions: tap, and long press. A bit like the Springboard app (home screen). I've implemented it as a UIButton with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer attached.

In some cases I need to disable the tap action which i do by setting `enabled = NO` on my button. But unfortunately this also disabled my gesture recogniser.

How do I disable the UIButton's standard behaviour while keeping the gesture recogniser attached to it active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton is a sub-class of UIControl.
Look at the various methods in UIControl.
You can specify specific methods to call for ControlEvents (such as ControlEventTouchUpInside a.k.a tap) and for UIEvents.

```
 - (void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event

 - (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

You can remove actions for control events with:

```
 - (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

Or, depending on your conditions, you can just no-op inside the target/selector method that is called.

Answer (score 1):

You could remve the button's tap target and selector and then add it again when you need it. By setting `enabled = NO;` you are setting the UIControl's receivers to NO.

More Docs
[UIButton - Enabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl)